Vertex degrees in pinwheel tiling
What is known about the distribution of vertex degrees in the pinwheel tiling ?
In particular, is there a maximum degree?
From pictures, such as the one below, it seems that the maximum degree is 8. But is there a proof?


The highest degree on the Conway decomposition is $5$ and it can be attached in to other vertices in two ways, one which is a reflection symmetry and the other which has a perpendicular bisector. Both of those cases have degree $8$ and from the Conway decomposition we see that this is maximal by counting the number of triangles touching the right angle vertex and the vertex of degree $5$.

The Pinwheel tilings have finite local complexity up to Euclidean motions (translations and rotations), so there are only finitely many 'vertex types' up to rotation. There are standard techniques for calculating the frequency of patches in a substitution tiling. In particular, here you want to look at patches associated with vertex types.

Yes, the maximum degree is 8. The only angles that can occur at a vertex of a tiling are $\pi, \pi/2,\arctan(2), \arctan(1/2)$. Since $\arctan(2)$ and $\arctan(1/2)$ are irrational multiples of $\pi$ but $\arctan(2)+\arctan(1/2)=\pi/2$, there must be equally many small and large acute angles at any vertex. From there it's easy to see that you can't fit more than 8 angles together at a vertex without going over 360 degrees of total internal angle.
